# accessing non-statics from static method in groovy "script"

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy script named myScript.groovy that i run from command line using "java cp . myScript". 
I am trying to add log4j logger to it, but keep getting the can't access non-static variable from static method kind of errors, and if i define logger as static the compiler complains saying i can't do that. The problem i realize is because this is a groovy script, and not a class.

I've tried the @Field, and @Log4j annotations without any luck. Can someone plz help me understand how to do this?

Following is how my code looks like:

### myScript.groovy

```
def var1 = getVar1()
def var2 = getVar2()

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

// @Log4j here gave compilation error
def static void doSomething()
{
    // do something

    // how to access log from this static method? defining log as static throws compilation error
    log.info "trying to access logger from static method"

}
```

Comment: Is there some reason the doSomething method must be static?

Answer (score 0):

The @Log Annotation must be annotated on a class.

The following example from the docs works

```
import groovy.util.logging.*

@Log
class Car {
    Car() {
        log.info 'Car constructed'
    }
}

def c = new Car()
```

Comment: Based on Jeffrey answer I want to add link to [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_logging_improvements).

Answer (score 0):

If you need your method to be static, and if passing a parameter to the static method isn't a good option, you could have the method get its own reference to the named logger.

```
def static void doSomething()
{
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName())
    // do something

    // how to access log from this static method? defining log as static throws compilation error
    log.info "trying to access logger from static method"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because if i add more methods that need to use the logger, i'll have to pass logger to all those methods.